# Apple Macintosh 1984 OS 0.8.5/or similar on RPI2

Tags: operating-systems

Is there any way to install the Apple OS 0.8.5/or similar (Macintosh 1984) on a raspberry pi 2?
(with an emulator or something)

Comment: The Motorola 68k processor, used in the original Mac and various video game machines of the time, seems to have an [emulator in RetroPie](https://github.com/RetroPie/mame4all-pi/tree/master/src/cpu/m68000).

Comment: @goldilocks thx